# Dealing with pgf keys in multiple namespaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have macros which take a list of keys as argument and pass this list on to `\tikzset`s which each use a specific namespace. In the example below macros of this type would be `\marmot` and `\koala`. This works all well so far.

Now I'd like to call another macro (let's call it `\thing`) from within these macros, which again has a `\tikzset` with a unique namespace.

At the moment I simply pass the complete list of keys to the `\thing` macro, which results in two possibilities:

- either it complains about unknown keys, for example if `hat,teeth` is passed to `marmot`, `\thing` only knows `hat` but not `teeth`, which is a key for the `marmot`
- to workaround I can add `/marmot,/koala` to `.search also`, but this gets quite annoying to maintain as soon as there is a large number of different macros which can call `\thing`

Are there better ways to deal with this quagmire?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% things %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\thing}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/thing/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
    \end{scope}%
}

\tikzset{
  /thing/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,
    /marmot,/koala % HERE: I'm looking for a better way than to list all possible namespaces
  },
  /thing/.cd,
  hat/.code = {},
}

% marmot %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\marmot}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/marmot/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[brown] (0.15,-0.3) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
    \end{scope}%
    \thing[#1]%
}

\tikzset{
  /marmot/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,/thing},
  /marmot/.cd,
  teeth/.code = {},
}

% koala %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\koala}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/koala/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[gray] (0.15,-0.3) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
    \end{scope}%
    \thing[#1]%
}

\tikzset{
  /koala/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,/thing},
  /koala/.cd,
  sleep/.code = {},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\thing[hat]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[teeth]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\koala[sleep]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[hat,teeth]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Second level of craziness**

To make things even more complicated, I also have a macro where I don't know in advance if I end up with a marmot or koala

```
% tikzling %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{tikzlings}{{\marmot}{\koala}}
\newcommand{\tikzling}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{%
      /thing/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,/marmot,/koala}
    }
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\tikzlingrandom}{tikzlings}%
    \tikzlingrandom[#1]
}
```

which means that `\tikzling[hat,teeth]` will cause an error half the time...

> In case it would help anybody to see the full code, it is available from https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings

Comment: I'm not sure if `namespaces` is the correct term, if someone knows a better word, please tell.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what the logic you are trying to implement looks like. Do you want inapplicable options to do nothing? In that case, you can set the unknown option handler to be a no-op instead of an error.

Comment: It seems to me that if the macro has its own namespace, then the calling macro needs to determine which options are appropriate and pass _only_ those. That is what you would need to do if you were to invoke a macro that was written by someone else.  Otherwise, why not just use the same namespace and let the sub macros access it directly rather than passing it in.

Comment: @HoodChatham That would probably be an easy workaround. Would you happen to have an example how to do this?

Comment: @PeterGrill Very good point! I don't see any disadvantages of one single namespace with my MWE. I'll text with the complete project and report back.

Comment: @PeterGrill The problem with a common namespace is that if multiple animals define the same key, it is overwritten each time and works only for the last animal (each animal has its own `\tikzset` etc. because they should be useable both as individual packages and in combination)

Comment: @samcarter: So, the same key name has multiple meanings depending on which animal is called?

Comment: @PeterGrill Not necessarily different meanings, for example `body` is used in all of them to change the default body colour. But the same key can have different default values for different animals and they should work independent of each other - this means if I only load the marmot package the the key has to exist but also if I load both the marmot and the koala.

Comment: @samcarter: The way I would handle that is that there should be separate keys for the default values for each `body` depending on the animal. Thus `body` is reserved for user specified value and `marmot default body` is used _only_ if the user did not specify `body`.

Comment: @PeterGrill That sounds as if it might work. Let me check!

Comment: You can at least avoid the errors in `\tikzling` if add `.unknown` handlers, such as `.unknown/.code = { \typeout{marmot: #1 unknown}}` to your marmots and koalas. Of course, the handler above only prints a message to the log file and ignores the error, which is probably not what you want.  You should be able to make the unknown handlers do something more sensible, but exactly what this is probably depends on koala-marmot interactions, which I am not a specialist in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to avoid the keys that are not in the current namespace, but you don't want to do anything with them in this place, what you can do is just `\relax` all unknown stuff.

```
\pgfkeys{/thing/.unknown/.code=\relax}
```

The keys are going to be called again in the other commands, so their definition will not be lost.
The drawback, of course, is that you can not do anything specific with those unknown keys because all will be `\relax`ed.

This works:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% things %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\thing}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/thing/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
    \end{scope}%
}

\pgfkeys{/thing/.unknown/.code=\relax}

\tikzset{
  %/thing/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,
    %/marmot,/koala % HERE: I'm looking for a better way than to list all possible namespaces
  %},
  /thing/.cd,
  hat/.code = {},
}

% marmot %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\marmot}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/marmot/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[brown] (0.15,-0.3) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
    \end{scope}%
    \thing[#1]%
}

\pgfkeys{/marmot/.unknown/.code=\relax}

\tikzset{
  %/marmot/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,/thing},
  /marmot/.cd,
  teeth/.code = {},
}

% koala %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\koala}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/koala/.cd,#1}%
        \fill[gray] (0.15,-0.3) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
    \end{scope}%
    \thing[#1]%
}

\pgfkeys{/koala/.unknown/.code=\relax}

\tikzset{
  %/koala/.search also={/tikz,/pgf,/thing},
  /koala/.cd,
  sleep/.code = {},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\thing[hat]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[teeth]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\koala[sleep]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[hat,teeth]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tested it and it works great! If you don't mind I'll wait a tiny bit longer before I accept it for a totally selfish reason: I hope to get a palindrome number in my reputation soon and if I would accept your answer right know, I would get 2 points which would destroy my chances for the palindrome :)

Comment: No problem at all ;-) It is not an elegant solution, so maybe somebody with more knowledge comes with something better. I hope you get your palindrome.

Comment: I forgot to say that .unknown/.code=\relax can be added to the \tikzset itself.

Comment: I think it is an easy approach. And because the `\thing` macro is primarily designed to be called  from within another command, the outer command already throws an error if a totally wrong key is used. So I think this is relativity low risk as one still notice if there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding about the delay in accepting your answer - in case it is any consolation: it worked :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqGWB.png

Comment: Thx! Now I have got exactly 1800 rep :-D

Comment: Cool! Congratulations :)